# Django/Python: Pulling value from template into views.py

Tags: python, json, django, api

I currently have a search function in my views.py file like so:

```
def json_search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    api_key = locu_api
    url = 'https://api.locu.com/v1_0/venue/search/?api_key=' + api_key
    locality = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    category = 
    final_url = url + "&locality=" + locality + "&category=" + category
    json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(final_url)
    decoded_data = json.load(json_obj)
    return render(request, 'loc_search.html',
                       {'objects': decoded_data['objects']})
```

What I have set up is a drop-down search bar whereby I want the category variable within my json_search() function to automatically be assigned to the selected option on the drop-down bar before the form is submitted using the submit button. The search bar looks like this :

[image]

And the code like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}">
<div class="input-group">
        <input name="query" input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder="City or Zipcode" class="form-control datebox">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
            <button name = "category_query" tabindex="-3" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <li><a href="restaurants">Resturant</a></li>
                <li><a href="active">Activities</a></li>
                <li><a href="bars">Bar / Club</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="other">other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to get the value back to the backend *view* code in some fashion in order for that to happen.

It would be possible to do so prior submitting the form. For example, you could use an *Ajax* call within the template code to hit the same *URL* serviced by the `json_search` function, passing `category` in the URL, and then pulling it out of `request.GET`.

If you wanted it to be assigned upon dropdown selection, you would want to attach a `click` *event handler* via *jQuery* to that dropdown, and then in that handler's function, get the selected value, and then add it to the *Ajax* call back to your `json_search` function.

In your `json_search` code, you'll want to differentiate handling the submit (which should be a `POST`) vs. general `GET` handling (perhaps based on whether various parameters are present in the *URL*).

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

It's certainly not trivial, especially if you've not worked with *Ajax* before, but it shouldn't be too bad overall (and once you get the hang of it, this paradigm can be used for all sorts of interaction with other modules like *Datatables* and many others, not to mention your own *Django* backend).

While there are many different ways to do this, I'm a fan of using *jQuery*'s [`when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) in conjunction with `done` (used in examples on the same page). The `when` lets you fire off multiple asynchronous *Ajax* requests, and the `done` acts as a join point where you wait for them to finish before proceeding.

Comment: Sounds a lot of work, I have very little experience with Ajax is well :/ guess thats my night gone :')

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, you would make all the links in the dropdown have a `onclick` handler which would need to save the category. Then instead of a `url` for the form you would use a `submit` function which would send your form data + the `category`.

That is something easy to do with `angular` + `ui.bootstrap`.

---

### with jQuery

http://plnkr.co/edit/iBY2n9dq8Tn95IUGwNAB?p=preview

You need to transform your links not to have a valid `href` and instead call a function, e.g.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="setCategory('restaurant')">Restaurant</a>
```

and add a hidden field for the category

```
<input name="category" input="" id="category" type="hidden" placeholder="Category" class="form-control" />
```

and some easy javascript

```
function setCategory(category) {
  alert('category (hidden) = ' + category);
  $('#category').val(category);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to implement angular and ui bootstrap into what i have at the moment?

Comment: So i have just read through the documentation, essentially what I would be looking mainly at is allowing the client to invoke a method from django view? or would I be needing to implement some basic crud operations is well. Sorry to bother